# how to compare and filter 2 arrays of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I am doing an app in React with typescript and I am having a issue when comparing two states(which basically are 2 objects arrays and filtering so I only get back the ones that are ont included in `allBooks` array, this is the interfaces:

```
export interface IBook {
  book_id: number;
  book_name: string;
  release_year: number;
}
```

then the states of my class:

```
class Home extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      users: [],
      userBooks: [],
      allBooks: []
    };
  }
```

and then the compare function:

```
 filterBooks = () => {
    const { allBooks, userBooks } = this.state;
    let notUserBooks = allBooks.filter(
      ({ book_id }: { book_id: number }) => !userBooks.includes({book_id}));
    console.log(notUserBooks, allBooks);
  };`
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong but the console.log I get the same results in notUserBooks than in allBooks, I mean the allBooks has 3 items in it, and in the console log after the filter I get the whole 3 items....this is the console output:

````
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {book_name: "the lord of the rings", release_year: 1950}
1: {book_name: "the butterfly", release_year: 1980}
2: {book_name: "the hobbit", release_year: 1960}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0) 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {book_name: "the lord of the rings", release_year: 1950}
1: {book_name: "the butterfly", release_year: 1980}
2: {book_name: "the hobbit", release_year: 1960}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)```
````

Comment: Whats the problem? what is the result you are getting?

Comment: I am getting an empty array in ````console.log(notUserBooks)````

Comment: Do you want to pick up those books that don't exist in the userBooks array?

Comment: Can you post the sample data of allBooks and userBooks ? I dont know the data structure of each object in 2 array.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
 filterBooks = () => {
    const { allBooks, userBooks } = this.state;
    let notUserBooks = allBooks.filter(
      ({ book_id }: { book_id: number }) => !userBooks.includes({book_id}));
    console.log(notUserBooks);
  };
```

to this:

```
 filterBooks = () => {
    const { allBooks, userBooks } = this.state;
    let notUserBooks = allBooks.filter(
      ({ book_id }: { book_id: number }) => !userBooks.map(book => book.book_id).includes(book_id));
    console.log(notUserBooks);
  };
```

In general, you cannot compare Objects in javascript. A simple test:

```js
const a = { test: 'test' };
const b = { test: 'test' };
alert(a === b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if `userBooks` contains the book item:

```
let notUserBooks = allBooks.filter((book) => !userBooks.some((userBook) => userBook.book_id === book.book_id));

console.log(notUserBooks);
```

Comment: I do not know what I am doing wrong but the console.log I get the same results in notUserBooks than in allBooks, I mean the allBooks has 3 items in it, and in the console log after the filter I get the whole 3 items....

Comment: Can you post the console output `allBooks` and `userBooks` contents?

Comment: I cannot see `book_id` fields in the output you posted. It may be the problem.

Comment: OMG.... problem solved, thanks guys, sorry for being silly... hehe

Answer (score 0):

Objects are reference types so you can’t just use === or == to compare objects.
One solution for your filter method is (It is split into 2 methods):

```
const bookIds = (books: IBook[]): number[] => !!books && books.map(({bookId})=> bookId);

const filterBooks = (userBooks: IBook[], allBooks: IBook[]): IBook[] => 
  !!allBooks && allBooks.filter(({bookId}) => bookIds(userBooks).indexOf(bookId) === -1 );
```

[In this project you can see it better](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gzajaq) (with Typescript & React)